# Device authentication with Titanium

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, titanium

We are considering using Titanium to develop for Android and iPhone version of an application originally made for Blackberry. However, we want the authenticate the device and not through the traditional method (username + password). In the case of Blackberry, we use Blackberry PIN  to authenticate devices against a database of a web service. We think using the IMEI of the device, but do not know how safe it is.

Does anyone know a way to authenticate a device using a similar method? Is it possible to extract the IMEI of a team using Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

There are standard calls that allow us to authenticate by MEID on handset, (`PlatformMgr.getPlatform().getDeviceId()` comes to mind for android). You can get this and encrypt it with AES 128-bit encryption (`IcryptoManager` package) and use it for authentication.

I dont remember off the top of my head for iphone but I am sure something similar exists there too.